# Transform String args[] into an object

Tags: java, arguments, program-entry-point

I need to parse the command line arguments and transform them into a Java object.

My command line to run the Java .jar:

```
java -cp "combo.jar" com.ascurra.Main --time=3 --limit=5000 --initDate=2017-01-01.13:00:00
```

I need transform the arguments `--time=3 --limit=5000 --initDate=2017-01-01.13:00:00` into an object and save it to my database.

How do this in an elegant way?

Comment: I would start by putting some effort into solving this problem yourself.

Comment: See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)  and show what you tried

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a stream of the `args` array, `map` to retain the part of the string needed i.e:

```
String[] resultArray = Arrays.stream(args)
                             .map(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 1))
                             .toArray(String[]::new);
```

the array should now contain:

```
[3, 5000, 2017-01-01.13:00:00]
```

in which case you can index into this array, then convert to any other type needed and populate your custom object.

---

Alternatively, as there are only 3 arguments, you could skip creating the stream entirely and just index into the array along with the use of `substring` to retain the parts needed. However, the approach above is more adaptable as if you were to enter more arguments, you need not change anything within your code in terms of retrieving the arguments.

Comment: I need keep the atributes in an object to get in another time.

Comment: @MisterB see edit. I've simplified the solution a bit but this is as far as I can go as I don't know the type of the Java object you're talking about within your post.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create a Class with the corresponding fields

```
class Entry {

    private int time;
    private int limit;
    private Date initDate;

    public Entry() {
    }

    public Date getInitDate() {
        return initDate;
    }

    public void setInitDate(Date initDate) {
        this.initDate = initDate;
    }

    public int getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }

    public void setLimit(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

Then create an object of this class and parse the arguments to set the values

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String arg : args) {  // get the options from the arguments
        if (arg.startsWith("--")) {
            options.add(arg.replace("--", ""));
        }
    }
    Entry entry = new Entry();

    for (String option : options) {
        String[] pair = option.split("=");
        if (pair.length == 2) {
            if (pair[0].equals("time")) { // parse time option
                entry.setTime(Integer.parseInt(pair[1])); 
            } else if (pair[0].equals("limit")) { // parse limit option
                entry.setLimit(Integer.parseInt(pair[1]));
            } else if (pair[0].equals("initDate")) { // parse initDate option
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss");
                try {
                    entry.setInitDate(sdf.parse(pair[1]));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(entry.getLimit() + " , " + entry.getTime() + " , "
            + entry.getInitDate());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> how do this in an elegant way?

These three information(`--time=3 --limit=5000 --initDate=2017-01-01.13:00:00`) are passed as a specific element in `String[] args` of the main class.
Parsing them is really not a complex task (`String.substring()` or a regex will do the job).
But a good parser should also be able to not be annoyed by the order of arguments and should also think to produce relevant debugging information during data mapping to specific type as date or numeric types.
At last, adding or removing a supported parameter should be easy and safe and getting commands help could also be desirable.

So as first advise, if you can use a library, don't reinvent the wheel and use
[Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/cli/) or better use [arg4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/) that is reall simple to use and avoid boiler plate code.

If you cannot, at least inspire you from them.

**Apache Commons CLI example**

For example to create  `Option`s (arguments) :

```
public static final String TIME_ARG = "time";
public static final String LIMIT_ARG = "limit";
...

Options options = new Options();   
options.addOption("t", TIME_ARG, true, "current time");
options.addOption("l", LIMIT_ARG, true, "limit of ...");
...
```

Then parse `Options` and retrieve value of it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  ...
  try{
    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
    ...
    // then retrieve arguments
    Integer time = null;
    Integer limit = null;
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = null;

    String timeRaw = cmd.getOptionValue(TIME_ARG);
    if (timeRaw.matches("\\d*")) { 
       time = Integer.valueOf(timeRaw); 
    }
    ...and so for until you create your object to save 
    MyObj obj = new MyObj(time, limit, localDateTime);
    ...
   }
   catch(ParseException exp ) {
      System.out.println( "Unexpected exception:" + exp.getMessage() );
   }
}
```

**args4j example**

args4j is much straight to use.
Besides, it provides some converters (from `String` to specific types) but date conversion is not provided out of the box.

 So you should create your own handler to do that.example.

In the example, `LocalDateTimeOptionHandler` must so implement `[OptionHandler][3]`.

```
import org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineException;
import org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser;
import org.kohsuke.args4j.Option;
import org.kohsuke.args4j.OptionHandlerFilter;

public class SampleMain {

    @Option(name = "--time", usage = "...")
    private Integer time;

    @Option(name = "--limit", usage = "..")
    private Integer limit;

    @Option(name="--initDate", handler=LocalDateTimeOptionHandler.class, usage="...")
    private LocalDateTime initDate;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       new SampleMain().doMain(args);
    }

    public void doMain(String[] args) throws IOException {
      CmdLineParser parser = new CmdLineParser(this);

      try {
        // parse the arguments.
        parser.parseArgument(args);        
       } catch (CmdLineException e) {
         System.err.println(e.getMessage());
         System.err.println("java SampleMain [options...] arguments...");
         parser.printUsage(System.err);
         System.err.println("  Example: java SampleMain" + parser.printExample(OptionHandlerFilter.ALL));
         return;
       }

      if (time != null)
        System.out.println("-time is set");

      if (limit != null)
        System.out.println("-limit is set");

      if (initDate != null)
        System.out.println("-initDate is set");

    }
 }
```

Comment: I receive this error when my args has a "--" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The option '--time' contains an illegal character : '-'
 at org.apache.commons.cli.OptionValidator.validateOption(OptionValidator.java:71)
 at org.apache.commons.cli.Option.<init>(Option.java:146)

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot. To be able to pass parameter with `-`, you have to use the Option constructor that specifies a **longOpt String** as parameter. I updated

Comment: I dislike Commons CLI. Something like [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) or [Args4J](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/) is far more elegant.

Comment: @Boris the Spider Thank you for the feedback. I note it. I used  Commons CL very long ago. It gave a good result but the API was indeed not very pleasant to use.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found - it's a somewhat arcane API. And it hasn't gotten any less arcance over the years.